# test multiple object update form with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, automated-tests

i have the following method to update multiple objects at once in a single form:

```
def update_by_day
  company_calendars = CompanyCalendar.find(params[:company_calendars_ids])
  company_calendars.each do |company_calendar|
    unless update_calendar_params(company_calendar, params["company_calendar_" + company_calendar.id.to_s])
      render js: "alert('Start time must be smaller then End time');"
      break
    end
  end
end

def update_calendar_params(company_calendar, calendar_params)
  company_calendar.time_from = company_calendar.time_from.change(:hour => calendar_params["time_from(4i)"], :min => calendar_params["time_from(5i)"])
  company_calendar.time_to = company_calendar.time_to.change(:hour => calendar_params["time_to(4i)"], :min => calendar_params["time_to(5i)"])
  company_calendar.save
end
```

The form keeps the objects ids on a hidden field:

```
<%= form_for(:company_calendar, url: {action: "update_by_day"}, method: :put, remote: true) do |f| %>    
  <% company_calendars.each do |company_calendar| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "company_calendars_ids[]", company_calendar.id%>
```

Not the most elegant piece of code, but works fine.

Now i'm having problems writing the test. This is what i got so far:

```
it "updates all calendars from correspondent day" do
    company_calendar = FactoryGirl.create(:company_calendar, company_id: @company.id )
    put :update_by_day, {:day => company_calendar.day, company_id: @company.to_param, :company_calendar => { time_from: "2014-09-25 08:00:00", time_to: "2014-09-25 12:00:00" }, :format => :js  }
    expect(company_calendar.time_from).to eq( "2014-09-25 08:00:00" )
end
```

It throws the following Error:

```
Couldn't find CompanyCalendar without an ID
```

Route doesnt use id:

```
/companies/:company_id/company_calendars/update_by_day(.:format)
```

So im don't know how to pass the arguments.

Well, I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass `company_calender_id` in `params` in specs, because you are passing it through hidden field and using it to find record in first line of update_by_day action.
Try below one:

```
put :update_by_day, {:day => company_calendar.day, company_id: @company.to_param, :company_calendar => { time_from: "2014-09-25 08:00:00", time_to: "2014-09-25 12:00:00" },:company_calendars_ids => company_calendar.id, :format => :js  }
```